# Dual boot - latest 2 "original" Android & iPhone versions on a phone

Tags: android, iphone, ios, testing, boot

For testing purposes we need to test our product on specified Android/Iphone devices with the 2 latest Android/iOS versions each.
Is there a way to install some sort of dual boot, so we have practically 2x the same device, for example the Samsung Galaxy SII with the originally released 2.3.5 and 4.0.3 installed?
As Samsung, HTC etc. customize the Android OS (with different versions depending where you live) it has to be the exact same version as if you follow the regular "update" process of that device here in Switzerland.
I assume there's no way to do this on an iPhone, as jailbreak is definitely not an option (after all this is a customized version...) but I have a spark of hope that there's some nice solution for Android.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Regards
ABBDVD

PS: We test on the Android SDK too, of course, but the customization makes it not releavant.

Comment: You mean dual boot two different versions on one device? Like Gingerbread and ICS?

Comment: This is the closest I've seen dual booting on Android devices, keeping in mind your specific requirement. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drx2.bootmanager&hl=en. No clue about the OS versions it supports. That said, this question seems to be more about usage than actual programming. Perhaps moving it to http://android.stackexchange.com/ would be a better option.

Comment: could be Gingerbread & ICS, but also 2.3.4 and 2.3.5
Just the latest 2 released versions for that phone...

I didn't know there exists android.stackexchange.com
Is there a way to move the thread or should I delete it here and open a new one there?
The suggested Boot Manager is not really an option I guess :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible to do for the iPhone, and probably a bad idea on Android phones.

You want to test on clean devices, not create another set of problems by using hacks and strange bootloaders. If your product is worth it, drop the few hundred € for a used device. Less hassle, better results. And don't forego on-device testing. You cannot judge performance in the simulators, and can't get a good feel for the interactions as well.

Comment: well I hoped there's an option without hacks and strange bootloaders ;) I was hoping for some way to copy maybe the currently installed OS and then being able to choose between these two.

Comment: Maybe there are options for Android, I honestly don't know (but I don't think there are any "clean and official" ones, especially for branded phones). What I'm saying is, I don't think you should pursue those: Rebooting will take time, making testing tedious, and the systems won't be *exactly* as they are for users.